# How to parse repetitive string into array of objects in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have a the attributes of several objects in a single long string, separated by a "|", like this:

```
branches = "001|lat1|lon1|Name1|002|lat2|lon2|Name2|003|lat3|lon3|Name3|004|lat4|lon4|Name4"
headers = "ID|Latitude|Longitude|Name" //name of attributes 
fieldCount = "4" //4 attributes per object
```

I need to transform that into a propper array of objects in JavaScript, like this:

```
[
    {
        "ID": "001",
        "latitude": "lat1",
        "longitude": "lon1",
        "name": "Name1"
    },
    {
        "ID": "002",
        "latitude": "lat2",
        "longitude": "lon2",
        "name": "Name2"
    },
    {
        "ID": "003",
        "latitude": "lat3",
        "longitude": "lon3",
        "name": "Name3"
    },
    {
        "ID": "004",
        "latitude": "lat4",
        "longitude": "lon4",
        "name": "Name4"
    }
]
```

The question is how to accomplish this?

Comment: I would use `split` and a couple of loops.

Comment: I would create a list, split the branches var by |, then iterate every fieldCount and in the loop create the object with the fields and then add it to the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is split the strings to create arrays and loop through them popping off the front item from the branches array for each item in the headers array

```
var branches = "001|lat1|lon1|Name1|002|lat2|lon2|Name2|003|lat3|lon3|Name3|004|lat4|lon4|Name4";
var headers = "ID|Latitude|Longitude|Name";
branches = branches.split("|");
headers = headers.split("|");
var array=[];
while(branches.length){
    var x = {};
    for(i=0;i<headers.length;i++){
        x[headers[i]]=branches.shift();
    }
    array.push(x);
}
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var branches = "001|lat1|lon1|Name1|002|lat2|lon2|Name2|003|lat3|lon3|Name3|004|lat4|lon4|Name4";
var headers = "ID|Latitude|Longitude|Name"; //name of attributes 

var branchArray = branches.split("|");
var headerArray = headers.split("|");
var numFields = headerArray.length; //fieldCount is redundant
var objects = []; //result will be stored here
var currentObj = {};

for(var i = 0; i < branchArray.length; ++i) {
    var fieldIndex = i % numFields;
    // When we just put in the last field
    if(fieldIndex === (numFields - 1)) {
        if(currentObj) {
            objects.push(currentObj);
            currentObj = {};
        }
    }

    currentObj[headerArray[fieldIndex]] = branchArray[i];
}
```

There are edge cases like when number of fields in branches is not divisible by number of fields in headers but you did not specify clearly how to handle those.